# How can I get the system proxy settings (including username and password) with python?

Tags: python, windows-7, proxy, urllib2

I'm using Windows 7 and Python 2.7. I'm behind a corporate proxy with authentication.
Now I wrote a python program which shortly runs every 15 mins (by the windows scheduler) to retrieve data from the internet. This works fine, however, I have to hardcode the proxy settings (including username and password) or put them in a config file.

Is there an accecptable way (security-wise) to enter my proxy settings once at the beginning of my windows session and have them then available to my python program to access the internet via our proxy?

Answer (score 0):

if you have environment variables set, then something like this could work:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.getenv('PROXY')
>>> os.getenv('PROXY_USER')
>>> os.getenv('PROXY_PWD')
```

Comment: Thanks, Ayush. I also thought of this, but is it really better than saving my password in some config file? I mean in both cases we have plain text ...

Comment: @maitre_charles that is a different question, possibly suited for security.stackexchange.com